# Move log files to archive folder by date, but not the last log file for each process

Tags: shell, archive

I have these files, [processName.DateTime.out]

```
/stev/log: ls -al

drwxrwxr-x    1 user.stev           user         4096 Feb  5 23:59 .
drwxrwxr-x    1 user.stev           user         4096 Feb  5 23:59 ..
-rw-rw-r--    1 user.stev           user         4096 Jan 21 23:59 AAA01.202002010000.out
-rw-rw-r--    1 user.stev           user         4096 Jan 22 23:59 AAA01.202002020000.out
-rw-rw-r--    1 user.stev           user         4096 Jan 23 23:59 AAA01.202002030000.out
-rw-rw-r--    1 user.stev           user         4096 Feb  1 23:59 BBB01.202002010000.out
-rw-rw-r--    1 user.stev           user         4096 Feb  2 23:59 BBB01.202002020000.out
-rw-rw-r--    1 user.stev           user         4096 Feb  3 23:59 BBB01.202002030000.out
-rw-rw-r--    1 user.stev           user         4096 Feb  1 23:59 DDD01.202002010000.out
-rw-rw-r--    1 user.stev           user         4096 Feb  2 23:59 DDD01.202002020000.out
-rw-rw-r--    1 user.stev           user         4096 Feb  3 23:59 DDD01.202002030000.out
-rw-rw-r--    1 user.stev           user         4096 Feb  1 23:59 TEST01.202002010000.out
-rw-rw-r--    1 user.stev           user         4096 Feb  2 23:59 TEST01.202002020000.out
-rw-rw-r--    1 user.stev           user         4096 Feb  3 23:59 TEST01.202002030000.out
-rw-rw-r--    1 user.stev           user         4096 Feb  1 23:59 TEST02.202002010000.out
-rw-rw-r--    1 user.stev           user         4096 Feb  2 23:59 TEST02.202002020000.out
-rw-rw-r--    1 user.stev           user         4096 Feb  3 23:59 TEST02.202002030000.out
-rw-rw-r--    1 user.stev           user         4096 Jan 21 23:59 TEST03.202002010000.out
-rw-rw-r--    1 user.stev           user         4096 Jan 22 23:59 TEST03.202002020000.out
-rw-rw-r--    1 user.stev           user         4096 Jan 23 23:59 TEST03.202002030000.out
```

And my script moves some files to archive folder if it is modified before 7 days.

```
sfind . -type f -mtime +7 -name "/stev/log" | while read FNAME
    do
        echo " moving file: " ${FNAME}      >> /stev/archive/archiveLog.log
        PCMD="mv ${FNAME} /stev/archive}"
        echo "PCMD=${PCMD}"                 >> /stev/archive/archiveLog.log
        eval "${PCMD}"                      >> /stev/archive/archiveLog.log
        echo ""                             >> /stev/archive/archiveLog.log
    done
```

this script will list below files then move them to the archive folder
[Current date: Feb 5]

```
-rw-rw-r--    1 user.stev           user         4096 Jan 21 23:59 AAA01.202002010000.out
-rw-rw-r--    1 user.stev           user         4096 Jan 22 23:59 AAA01.202002020000.out
-rw-rw-r--    1 user.stev           user         4096 Jan 23 23:59 AAA01.202002030000.out
-rw-rw-r--    1 user.stev           user         4096 Jan 21 23:59 TEST03.202002010000.out
-rw-rw-r--    1 user.stev           user         4096 Jan 22 23:59 TEST03.202002020000.out
-rw-rw-r--    1 user.stev           user         4096 Jan 23 23:59 TEST03.202002030000.out
```

But the thing is, I have to remain the last files for each process.

For example)
I can move belows files

```
-rw-rw-r--    1 user.stev           user         4096 Jan 21 23:59 AAA01.202002010000.out
-rw-rw-r--    1 user.stev           user         4096 Jan 22 23:59 AAA01.202002020000.out
-rw-rw-r--    1 user.stev           user         4096 Jan 21 23:59 TEST03.202002010000.out
-rw-rw-r--    1 user.stev           user         4096 Jan 22 23:59 TEST03.202002020000.out
```

but I should remain belows files
(It doesn't matter how many days ago, for the last file for each process has to be remained.)

```
-rw-rw-r--    1 user.stev           user         4096 Jan 23 23:59 AAA01.202002030000.out
-rw-rw-r--    1 user.stev           user         4096 Jan 23 23:59 TEST03.202002030000.out
```

Is there any good idea for this problems??

Comment: `-name "/stev/log"` will not work. `eval "${PCMD}"` is very unsafe.If you write all output to some log file, jsut redirect everything to the log file `do .... done >> /stev/archive/archiveLog.log`. `I have to remain the last files for each process` - so first you have to know which one is last. Ie. sort it. Then split it per "process". Then within each "process" extract all files except the last one. Then copy them. That's some stages, solve them one a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think in bash as in "streams" - something goes in, something goes out.

```
# find all files
find /stev/log -type f -mtime +7 |
# extract the part before dot
cut -d. -f1 |
# for each process
# could be transformed into `xargs sh -c '...' --` for speed
while IFS= read -r process; do
    # all files with this process
    find /stev/log -type f -mtime +7 -name "$process*" |
    # sort numerically second field behind dot
    sort -t. -n -k2 |
    # remove last file, because we don't want to move it
    # maybe you need to remove first line, then just sort -r, check it
    head -n -1
done |
# mv each file into /stev/archive
xargs -d$'\n' -I{} mv -v {} "/stev/archive" >> /stev/archive/archiveLog.log
```

Pass `-t` option to `xargs` to debug it.

Comment: Thank you KamilCuk,
Is there any alternative for maxdepth option?
Because my system is HPUX and i am using sh instead of bash.

Comment: find: bad option -maxdepth

Comment: I think, just remove it. It's a (very) micro-optimization that I am just used to and write because I am used to. It seems there are no directories inside `/stev/log`, so `find` has nowhere to descend into (recursively..). From [find HP-UX](https://nixdoc.net/man-pages/HP-UX/man1/find.1.html), I think could do `-path '/stev/log/$process*'`

Comment: Thanks a lot KamilCuk, I got most of essential idea from you.
Now I solved the issue and it works properly!